# curious: Why is IndexOutOfBounds exception different from emptyList exception in Rascal?

Tags: exception, rascal

Consider calling function foobar with  arguments,

```
list[int] exampleA=[1,2,3];
list[int] exampleB=[];

//call with under-sized list
foobar(exampleA); //everything ok, exception caught and handled

//call with empty list
foobar(exampleB); //throws an exception: emptyList

public void foobar(list[int] intList)
{
  try
  {
    int i=0;
    while(i<=5)
    {
        println(intList[i]);
        i++;
    }
  }
  catch IndexOutOfBounds(msg):
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Shouldn't IndexOutOfBounds technically be same as emptyList? What maybe the reason that these situations are considered two different exception conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

The exception `EmptyList` addresses the case where a function or operator expects a non-empty list as argument. For instance, taking the head of an empty list, as in `head([])`, gives this exception.

The exception `IndexOutOfBounds` is always associated with an illegal indexing operation on a list (`list`), list relation (`lrel`), string (`str`), or tuple (`tuple`) and involves an illegal index. This exception carries as extra information the offending index.

We make the distinction because for the `EmptyList` exception there is no clear offending index to report: the two exceptions carry therefore different information.